# Design: Implementing properties dependent on BaseClass Property

Tags: c#, inheritance, software-design

I Have a Base Class:

```
public abstract class TechObject {
    protected TechObject(FwVersion version) {
        FwVersion = version;
    }

    public FwVersion FwVersion { get; set; }
}
```

And I have another class that inherit this class.

```
public partial class PositioningAxis : TechObject {
    public PositioningAxis(FwVersion version) : base(version) {
    }
}
```

In this Class i automatically generated properties like this:

```
public partial class PositioningAxis {
    public int Drive_V3 { get; set; }
    public int Drive_V4 { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that only properties of V4 are visible when you create a object of class `PositioningAxis` with `FwVersion` V4.

I can change all classes however i want to, but i do not find a good pattern.

What i don't want is to create classes for each version. Also i dont want the user to see all properties from every Version of TechObject.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to mix compile time and runtime behaviour. How would you expect the body of a method declared `void DoSomething(PositioningAxis a) {...}` to work? How is it meant to know the complete history of its parameter up until now in order to determine whether `Drive_V4` is available or not?

Comment: If you're auto-generating classes, why muck about with `FwVersion`?  Just code-gen distinct classes `PositioningAxis3` and `PositioningAxis4` and be done with it.  That or follow the COM model and define interfaces like `IPositioningAxis3` and `IPositioningAxis4` that all share a common `IPositioningAxis` that can be freely used by your system and even used in methods as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your idea correctly, and this is probably not a good design. I would probably chose an interface and then implement a class for each version, but hey, that is just how I would do it. So, how about something like this:

```
public class FwVersion
{
    public int Version;
}

public abstract class TechObject
    {
        public FwVersion FwVersion { get; set; }
    }

public partial class PositioningAxis : TechObject
{
    private int Drive_V3
    {
        get; set;
    }
    private int Drive_V4
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int Drive
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.FwVersion.Version)
            {
                case 3: return Drive_V3;
                case 4: return Drive_V4;
                default: return -1;
            }
        }
        set 
        {
            switch (this.FwVersion.Version)
            {
                case 3: Drive_V3 = value;
                    break;
                case 4: Drive_V4 = value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like i can work with something like that. the problem with classes for each version is, that they will exceed in the later progress and would be about 100+ classes at the end.

Comment: I should not  stick my nose into your business, but this seems like a bad design from the beginning to me. In any case, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Unfortunately it is, I'm new in the architectual business... was a coding monkey in the past. But I now changed my mind and go for a complete different design. hopefully it will be better. Thanks anyway

Comment: Where is the _"interface"_?  You would probably be better off using an _implementation pattern_ then a mass of `case` statements

Comment: That is what I used the "would". I would use an interface and then implementation for every version, but @Yggras asked specifically not to do that.